# Clickable navigation bar with sub menu

Tags: javascript

I want to make a clickable navigation bar... The problem is when i click on it the sub menu should display but I want to perform another event on it , so when a click on it again, the sub menu will display none

I simply add 'addEventListner' with click and make it display block when click on it....

Comment: Hey there! Welcome to the community! Before you post a question, be sure to check out the helpful guide at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. This way, others can easily understand and help you with your problem. Have a great day!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To perform multiple conditions based on the number of clicks, you can initial `counterClick` and do whatever you want depending on result of modulo division. To test this code, just click every time at the home sub-menu.

```js
let counterClick = 0;
let subMenu = document.getElementById("sub-menu");

subMenu.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if(counterClick % 2 == 0) {
    // do whatever you want
    subMenu.classList.add('active');
  } else {
    subMenu.classList.remove('active');
    subMenu.style.display = "none";
  }
  counterClick++;
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li id="sub-menu"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```